# Скачивание комментариев с Ютуба

Tags: youtube

Здравствуйте. Есть задача скачать несколько тысяч коммов со страницы Ютуба к видео, со всеми вложенными ответами и т.д. Вроде для этого используют нижеприводимую команду, в которую по аналогии пытался вносить значения с исходного кода страницы и затем запуская в браузере, но вместо предполагаемого json, ответ приходит о запрещенном доступе. Прошу подсказать, как правильно формировать запрос:

```
https://www.youtube.com/comment_service_ajax
?action_get_comments=1
&pbj=1
&ctoken=QUFFLUhqa2tLalYySl82RF9yN0o4LTRVZnpBR1ZCREthZ3w
&itct=CAUQsV4iEwivwJDDxdXZAhUXqBgKHbbCC6go-B03A%3D%3D
```